# How can I exit i3 without using a mouse?

Tags: i3, exit

Whenever I go to exit i3 a bar shows up on the top giving me the ability to to click `Yes`, to exit, or `X` to cancel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is edit your i3 conf, to find out where that is out you can use `i3-config-wizard`,

```
$ i3-config-wizard
The config file "/home/$USER/.config/i3/config" already exists. Exiting.
```

The line that sets up the exit command is in that file, and it was created by default

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -b 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"
```

You'll see the `i3-nagbar`. That's the bar at the top responsible for nagging you. Just change that to go straight to the exit branch,

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+e exit
```

And finally run `i3-msg reload` to reload the configuration file.

Answer (score 17):

Add this to your config:

```
mode "exit: [l]ogout, [r]eboot, [s]hutdown" {

  bindsym l exec i3-msg exit

  bindsym r exec systemctl reboot

  bindsym s exec systemctl shutdown

  bindsym Escape mode "default"

  bindsym Return mode "default"

}

bindsym $mod+x mode "exit: [l]ogout, [r]eboot, [s]hutdown"
```

now use <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then choose <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, or <kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: My two cents: add `bindsym k exec i3lock; mode "default"` to get an `"exit: [l]ogout, [r]eboot, [s]hutdown, loc[k]"` mode.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this while wanting a way to exit i3 that was both keyboard-only and that I was unlikely to fat-finger. (Having $mod-Shift-e for exit and $mod-Shift-r for restart right next to each other is uncomfortable.) My solution is to use `dmenu` to run

`i3 exit` or `i3-msg exit`

In addition to being something that I can't accidentally type while trying to type something else, it has the advantages that it doesn't require any new configuration, and it reminds you how the shortcut keys work internally.